# How do I make a function in OCaml that takes in a list and a predicate and then returns the elements that don't satisfy the predicate?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

As the title suggests, I want to write a function that takes in an 'a list and an expression that evaluates to either true or false when elements of the list are passed into it. The function should return an 'a list of all the elements that don't satisfy the predicate given. The type should be 
                   `'a list -> ('a -> bool) -> 'a list` 
when it is working properly.

This is what I have so far,

```
let rec filter (x: 'a list) pred =
    if x = [] then [] else 
    if x -> pred = true then remove_if (x.tl) pred else
    x :: xs remove_if (x.tl) pred ;;
```

I tried some other ways of writing it but in my closest attempt the type ended up evaluating improperly.

Comment: So basically a filter function. You really should be using pattern matching on the list.

Comment: Did you start calling the function `remove_if` and then changed it to `filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started..

```
let rec filter f lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | hd::tl ->
    if (f hd)
    (*The rest of the function goes here*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Similar to what I had in a previous attempt but I think I see an error I may have made. What exactly is going on with the "(f hd)" part though?

Comment: That is the function(predicate) being applied to the head(hd). It should return true of false.